# Does the concept of "hot partition" in Cosmos DB only applies to provisioned throughput?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We all know that if the workload running on a logical partition consumes more than the throughput that was allocated to the underlying physical partition, it's possible that operations become rate-limited. This occurs when the workload is not evenly distributed on the several (logical) partitions, that is usually when a wrong partition key is selected for the document/container at creation time.

This performance problem is referred to as "hot partition".
But what if we provision the database as 'serverless', which is the mode where throughput is dynamically allocated, (not provisioned).
Does the issue still persist? If yes, why?

Comment: This really isn't a programming question, but also, it reads like an exam question. I suggest starting with the docs, and read up on the serverless offering, to see if that covers what you're looking for.

Comment: i studied the documentation, but the answer seems not be there/not be clear.
That's why i am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serverless isn't terribly helpful here and in workloads with sustained requests would be prohibitively expensive.

If you have persistent hot partitions, you may want to look into this feature here which is in preview. https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/distribute-throughput-across-partitions